# mock a method located in the __init__.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

I would like to mock a method which is in the **init**.py, but actually it is not working.

There is an example to demonstrate the issue and how I tried to write the unit test:

The code under test: src.main.myfile:

```
from src.main.utils import a_plus_b

def method_under_test():
    a_plus_b()
```

The a_plus_b is in the __init__.py in the src.main.utils module:

```
def a_plus_b():
    print("a + b")
```

The unittest:

```
import src.main.utils
import unittest
from mock import patch
from src.main.myfile import method_under_test

class my_Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def a_plus_b_side_effect():
       print("a_plus_b_side_effect")

    @patch.object(utils, 'a_plus_b')
    def test(self, mock_a_plus_b):
        mock_a_plus_b.side_effect = self.a_plus_b_side_effect
        method_under_test()
```

The unit test prints the "a + b", and not the side effect. Could anyone help me out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name you need to patch isn't `src.main.utils.a_plus_b`, but `src.main.myfile.a_plus_b`, since that is what `method_under_test` uses.

```
@patch('src.main.myfile.a_plus_b')
def test(self, mock_a_plus_b):
    mock_a_plus_b.side_effect = self.a_plus_b_side_effect
    method_under_test()
```

Comment: I was wondering why the method `src.main.utils.a_plus_b` could not be mocked. I allways patched the original methods, not the imported objects. Do you know any reason why can't I mock the `src.main.utils.a_plus_b`.

the other option for testing a_plus_b, if the method is passed as a keyword argument.

`
def method_under_test(_a_plus_b=a_plus_b):
    _a_plus_b()
`

Comment: If the code under test had simply used `import src.main.utils`, then called `src.main.utils.a_plus_b`, then the fully qualified name would be the correct thing to patch. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch.